# Limiting QuerySets in Django is not working

Tags: python, ajax, django

I just get no answer what is not working from Django. Django says everything is okay. I want to limit the results I get from my database. In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) is said that the first parameter is the offset and the second how much results I get beginning with the offset + 1. What I am doing wrong here ?

When I do not limit the queries everything works fine. So the mistake should be by using the limitation.

**views.py**

```
def ajax_more(request):
    categoryid = request.GET.get('categoryid', None)
    query = request.GET.get('query', None)
    offset = request.GET.get('offset', None)

    if query:
        if categoryid == "6":
            advertisements = Advertisement.objects.filter(title__contains=query)[int(offset): 2]
        else:
            advertisements = Advertisement.objects.filter(category__id=categoryid, title__contains=query)[int(offset): 2]
    else:
        if categoryid == "6":
            advertisements = Advertisement.objects.all()[int(offset): 2]
        else:
            advertisements = Advertisement.objects.filter(category__id=categoryid)[int(offset): 2]


    advertisements_list = []
    for advertisement in advertisements:
         advertisements_list.append({
            'id': advertisement.id, 
            'description': advertisement.description,
            'title': advertisement.title,
            'picture_url': advertisement.image.url,
            'date': advertisement.date })

    data = { 'advertisements_list': advertisements_list }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: check your "offset" value

Comment: offset = request.data.get('offset', 0)

Comment: "offset" is working fine. I get it from ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood how slicing works in Python. The `2` doesn't mean return two items, it means stop at the 2nd item (0 index) and don't include it. If offset is 2 or more, then your sliced queryset will be empty.

If you want to include two items, then you want:

```
advertisements = Advertisement.objects.all()[int(offset):int(offset)+2]
```

Comment: Thought about something like that but i did not understand how it works properly. Now i know it, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can do your query simple by only one slice:

```
if query:
    if categoryid == "6":
        advertisements = Advertisement.objects.filter(title__contains=query)
    else:
        advertisements = Advertisement.objects.filter(category__id=categoryid, title__contains=query)
else:
    if categoryid == "6":
        advertisements = Advertisement.objects.all()
    else:
        advertisements = Advertisement.objects.filter(category__id=categoryid)

inteval = slice(int(offset), int(offset)+2))
for advertisement in advertisements[inteval]:
```